# Blocked process in c

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am working on some code to create a process that goes blocked and then ends, I have to be able to see the blocked state with ps.

I tried with this, but my C knowledge is not good. The code doesn't print anything.

Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //exit();
#include <unistd.h> //sleep();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    createblocked();
}

int pid;
int i;
int estado;

void createblocked() {
   pid = fork();

   switch( pid ) {
      case -1: // pid -1 error ocurred
         perror("error\n");
      break;
      case 0: // pid 0 means its the child process
         sleep(); // we put the child to sleep so the parent will be blocked.
         printf("child sleeping...");
      break;
      default: // !=0 parent process
         // wait function puts parent to wait for the child
         // the child is sleeping so the parent will be blocked 
         wait( estado );
         printf("parent waiting...\n");
         printf("Child terminated.\n");
         break;
   }
   exit(0);
}
```

It should be easy because its only a little program that goes blocked, but I am walking in circles I think. Any advice?

Comment: I hope this is linux/unix, so compile it with `gcc -Wall -Werror ...` first.

Comment: Doesn't sleep take a parameter?

Comment: Its Linux I tried     `gcc blockedstate.c -o blo`

Comment: And btw. the argument to `wait()` is `int *`, not `int`...

Comment: you missed a \n on the child sleeping printf, you may also want to add fflush(stdout) after every print and move  printf("parent waiting...\n"); before the wait.

Comment: Instead of sleep(xxx) you could use pause(). Pause is the ultimate blocking system call; since ia basically does nothing.

Comment: fyi, this does print the expected output when I run the code on my machine (mac osx lion)

Comment: right, i missed the #include for the sleep and also the parameter

Comment: okey, am gonna correct those suggestions

Comment: @Rkan rather than changing the title of your question to include the word "[solved]", you would typically choose one of the answers, and "accept" it by clicking the big green check.  This indicates to everyone, not only that the problem is "solved", but which answer provided the best/most-complete solution.

Comment: Okey, I will do it, thank you, I am new in the website.

Comment: Okey, my problems are solved, but.. how can I make it sleep **forever**? Can I write something like infinity as a parameter?? I suppose not.. any ideas?

Comment: @Rakan: as wildplasser said, try [pause()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause).  It will sleep "forever".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) takes a parameter: the number of seconds to sleep.  When you omit it, it tends to return immediately.

Also [wait()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) takes an `int *`, not an `int`.

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    createblocked();
}

int pid;
int i;
int estado;

void createblocked() {
    pid = fork();

    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1: // pid -1 error ocurred
            perror("error\n");
            break;
        case 0: // pid 0 means its the child process
            printf("child sleeping...\n");
            sleep(500); // we put the child to sleep so the parent will be blocked.
            break;
        default: // !=0 parent process
            // wait function puts parent to wait for the child
            // thechild is sleeping so the parent will be blocked 
            printf("parent waiting...\n");
            wait(&estado);
            printf("Child terminated.\n");
            break;

    }
    exit(0);
}
```

note: I also moved the `printf("parent waiting...\n")` *above* the call to `wait()`, so you should see it before the parent blocks waiting on the child.

edit: Also, include `<unistd.h>`.  While not strictly required in order for the program to work (on most systems), doing so will give you better compile-time error reporting for things like missing and/or incorrectly-typed function arguments.

Comment: What @Aubin says is true.  If you want to see "child sleeping..." you'll need to move that printf *before* the `sleep()` call as well.  I'll make the edit in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

man [sleep](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/)

man [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)

You should give the number of seconds as an argument in `sleep()`.

For `wait` and `sleep` include `<unistd.h>`

Comment: @Rkan : got your output or still have a problem